# Let $Q_1$ be an $m×n$ matrix with orthonormal columns and $Q_2$ be an $n×p$ matrix with orthonormal columns

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $Q_1$ be an $m×n$ matrix with orthonormal columns and $Q_2$ be an $n×p$ matrix with orthonormal columns. Show that $Q_1Q_2$ has orthonormal columns.

My proof.

Check if $Q^TQ = I$ for $Q_1Q_2$, check $(Q_1Q_2)^TQ_1Q_2 = Q_2^TQ_1^TQ_1Q_2 = Q_t^TIQ_2 = I$ so therefor I have proved my question

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @Luiz Cordeiro I was not sure if that was for orthonormal or orthogonal, I am looking for orthonormal

Comment: You are applying the right criterion. A matrix $A$ is orthogonal if $A^T A$ is diagonal, and ortonormal if $A^TA=I$.

Comment: okay thanks for your help